# SQL result to Comma separated horizontally

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following code, How can create a comma delimited list for my results:

Query:

```
SELECT  
    STUFF((SELECT  ',' + Task_ID
           FROM Tasks EE
           WHERE EE.Task_ID = E.Task_ID  
             AND E.Task_Loc = '8'
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS TaskList
FROM 
    Task E
WHERE  
    E.Task_Loc = '8'
```

My query result:

```
SER.011
WAS.002
```

Expected result:

```
SER.011, WAS.002
```

Comment: could you please share your source data sample

Comment: Already mentioned in questions (My Query Result)

Comment: Sql server 2008 or 2014?

Comment: Sql server 2014

Comment: Can we have the table scheme? I think that your problem is the 2 equalities at your where clause. But we cant be sure if we dont have example! So , try please only the WHERE E.Task_Loc='8' (without the 'EE.Task_ID=E.Task_ID') statement and give us more clues!!

Answer (score 1):

You code should be basically correct:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT  ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), Task_ID)
              FROM Tasks EE
              WHERE EE.Task_Loc = '8'
              FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 1, '') AS TaskList
```

Comment: @SamBinHam . . . Easily fixed.  You don't need a `FROM` clause in the outer query if you just want one row.